# How can imaginary $f(z) $have a maximum or minimium on an open set?

Tags: complex-analysis

I see that the book only mentions $\operatorname{Re(f)}$ and $|f(z)|$ cannot have a local maximum or minimum on D but it does not mention anything about imaginary $f(z)$......so they can have a maximum or minimum on open set? if so how do they have it?

Comment: Multiplying by $i$ switches real and imaginary parts (up to a sign) and makes max/mins of real parts into mins/maxes of imaginary parts.

Comment: @AdamHughes That mean both of the parts cannot achieve max/min an a domain containing open set

Comment: If you have an open connected set $\Omega$ then if $f(z)$ is any non-constant holomorphic function then $|f(x)|$ will not achieve a maximum/minimum on $\Omega$.  This is the maximum modulus principle and is satisfied by any non-constant holomorphic function.  You don't mention that your function is holomorphic, but I guess it is safe to assume so.